# Customizing Table CellColor Heat Map part 2

Tags: cellcolor

I am revisiting a previous question for which we have already a solution:

[Customizing Table CellColor Heat Map](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/515779/customizing-table-cellcolor-heat-map)

Is it possible to have two different color definitions for two different color themes within the same document please? E.g., Table heatmap 1 is red, heatmap 2 is blue?

Comment: Sorry for my failed edits. Your original link did not work. I tried to fix it because I thought it was just a misplaced `[` but this was not the case. Roll back did not work either. Please add a working link, and forgive me for the failed attempts.

Comment: No problem; I edited my post, here the link: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/515779/customizing-table-cellcolor-heat-map

Comment: Do you only have 2 tables with 2 different color themes, or will there be even more tables using thouse two (or even more) color themes?

Comment: I am using two types of tables like a template, one with lower values and one with higher values; to visually distinguish those two types I'd like to have control over the colors. They will appear in the document alternating: Table 1 (colorA), Table 2 (ColorB), Table 2 (colorA) and so on - Thanks for looking at this!

Answer (score 0):

Using `\renewcommand` works. Before the table to be colored put:

```
\def\colorModel{hsb} %You can use rgb or hsb
\renewcommand\ColCell[1]{
    \pgfmathparse{#1<70?1:0}  %Threshold for changing the font color into the cells
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=0\relax\color{black}\fi
    \pgfmathsetmacro\compA{0.7-#1/240}   %Component R or H
    \pgfmathsetmacro\compB{#1/100}       %Component G or S
    \pgfmathsetmacro\compC{0.3+1}        %Component B or B
    \edef\x{\noexpand\centering\noexpand\cellcolor[\colorModel]{\compA,\compB,\compC}}\x #1} 
\newcolumntype{F}[1]{>{\collectcell\ColCell}#1<{\endcollectcell}}
```

Before the next table comes again `\renewcommand` for using a previous color or any color theme. This way I can have more than two different color themes. MWE, at the above link.